# QGIS export to KML failed

Tags: qgis, kml, google-earth

I don't know what's going on. My project CRS and layer CRS are fine, although if I export them to the KML file, I have something weird in my Google Earth.

[image]

I tried also to export to Shapefile and add this layer as a new one, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try to follow following steps,

1. give the CRS as WGS 84 (Google earth prefer this CRS)
2. within **Select fields to export and their export options** please tick the only attributes you require, i.e. remove the unwanted attributes
3. with in **Geometry** please select **polygon** from the drop down

then try to export the file.

[image]

Comment: It didn't work for WGS 84. I tried with PseudoMercator is better, but I have to start over a whole work.

Comment: What are your project and layer CRS? Are there also issues adding the KML to QGIS?

Comment: with the above steps try to export it to CSV initially and import it back QGIS and re export to KML.

Answer (score 0):

9-2023, version 3.32.2 Lima, Export to KML sits and spins, despite choosing selected options as mentioned above in the answer. Help QGIS creators, please.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/257246)